# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: The object is already closed

Tags: java, h2, resultset

For the life of me I cannot see how it "is already closed"

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class RsetTest2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String dbpath = "jdbc:h2:c:/mydb;IFEXISTS=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE";

        Connection conn = null;
        System.setProperty("h2.bindAddress", "127.0.0.1");
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbpath, "sa", "sa"); 
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("success.  querying database for latest values...");

        Statement qry = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "select id from CONSTITUENTS where manager = 'abc' limit 1";                               
        ResultSet rset = qry.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rset.next()) {
            int id = rset.getInt("id");
            System.out.println(id);         
            qry.executeUpdate("insert into PAYREQUESTS (constituent, inblock) values (" + id + ", 238)");
        }
        rset.close();
        qry.close();    
    }
}
```

here is the output:

```
success.  querying database for latest values...
103
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: The object is already closed [90007-196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.checkClosed(JdbcResultSet.java:3208)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.next(JdbcResultSet.java:130)
    at RsetTest2.main(RsetTest2.java:22)
```

where 22 corresponds to the "while (rset.next()) {" line

the DB is returning values, see that println statement that gives us 103.

and even weirder, if I // comment out the executeUpdate line, it all completes normally

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: The object is already closed [90007-196]

Your problem is that you are reusing the SQL `Statement` inside of your `while` loop.  As soon as you call the `qry.executeUpdate(...)` method in the loop, the `ResultSet rset` associated with the previous statement is closed, hence the error.   It is the `while(rset.next())` statement that is called *after* the first `executeUpdate(...)` in the loop that fails.

If you use a *new* statement in the loop then it should work.

```
Statement qry = conn.createStatement();
String sql = "select id from CONSTITUENTS where manager = 'abc' limit 1";
ResultSet rset = qry.executeQuery(sql);
while (rset.next()) {
    int id = rset.getInt("id");
    System.out.println(id);
    // we can't reuse the same Statement here so we need to create a new one
    conn.createStatement().executeUpdate("insert into PAYREQUESTS ...");
}
```

You might consider keeping a collection of necessary updates and then issue the updates at the end of the loop.

> and even weirder, if I // comment out the executeUpdate line, it all completes normally

Yep, that sounds right.  Not weird at all.  :-)

Comment: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/sql/ResultSet.java, in teh close method says that it should be a no-op if its already closed. So maybe a drive implementation issue.

Comment: It's not the close @Yogesh_D, it's the fact that he is still using the `rset` after it has been closed.

Comment: got it.. the while(rset.next()) is the one causing the issue and not the close.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also for simplifying your code you can use **try-with-resources** statement that utilizes
`java.lang.AutoCloseable` interface, thus you can get rid of lines:

```
    rset.close();
    qry.close();
```

The whole block can look somehow like this:

```
        try (ResultSet rset = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select id from CONSTITUENTS where manager = 'abc' limit 1")) {
            String insertSQL = "insert into PAYREQUESTS (constituent, inblock) values ('%d', 238)";
            while (rset.next()) {
                int id = rset.getInt("id");
                Savepoint savePoint = conn.setSavepoint("beforeInsert");
                try {
                    conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(String.format(insertSQL, id));
                    conn.commit();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    conn.rollback(savePoint);
                    //log exception
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //log exception
        }
```

Since your connection has auto-commit mode equals `false` maybe it make sense to possible harmful action.