# Reading H2 database (jenkins-jobs.mv.db) for pipeline Maven plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins, jdbc, jenkins-pipeline, h2

I am using [Pipeline Maven Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Maven+Plugin) 3.5.5 with Jenkins 2.89.2.

Due to large amount of dependencies between Maven projects, we rely mostly on `snapshotDependencies()` to ensure that Jenkins jobs are triggered in the right order. I want to re-use data stored in `$JENKINS_HOME/jenkins-jobs/jenkins-jobs.mv.db` H2 database to graph dependencies between jobs, not only rely on deatures available in Jenkins GUI.

If I copy out the H2 db file away from JENKINS_HOME and try to connect I get this:

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group = 'com.h2database', module = 'h2', version = '1.4.196'),
    @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
])

import groovy.sql.Sql

def url = "jdbc:h2:file:/jenkins/jenkins-jobs/jenkins-jobs;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;MULTI_THREADED=1"

def user = "sa"
def password = "sa"
def driver = "org.h2.Driver"
def sql = Sql.newInstance(url, user, password, driver)

println(sql.executeQuery("SHOW TABLES"))
println(sql.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES"))
```

Result:

```
rs0: null
```

If instead I try to use simply `jdbc:h2:file:/jenkins/jenkins-jobs/jenkins-jobs.mv.db` (with mv.db extension) as url, the result is:

```
Caught: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [28000-196]
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [28000-196]
```

but it is not clear to me, where does this password come from. Trying above with no username or password at all gives this:

```
def user = ""
def password = ""
```

again ends with empty Results Set `rs0: null`

It is not clear to me, how is this db accessed and read - and if it requires password, then where does it come from?

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In retrospective, it looks like issue was not related specifically to Jenkins database.

INstead, it was because of using groovy Sql in wrong way. This question helped in getting answer [org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: The object is already closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50161066/org-h2-jdbc-jdbcsqlexception-the-object-is-already-closed).

Using `createQueryCommand` instead of `executeQuery` worked:

```java
query = sql.createQueryCommand("SHOW TABLES")
rs = query.execute()

while(rs.next()) {
    result = rs.getString(1)
    println(result)
}
```

Or in the simplest way possible:

```java
println(sql.rows("SHOW TABLES"))
```